# For all possible answers of $B,$ for how many cards will $A$ be able to know the number above for sure if $m=2, n=4?$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics

> We are given $n$ cards. Each card has a unique number written on it. Players $A$ and $B$ play a game. Each turn $A$ chooses $m$ different cards. Then $B$ sees all the chosen cards and say a number from one of the cards (no need to tell which card this number is from). $A$ can play as many turns as they want. For all possible answers of $B,$ for how many cards will $A$ be able to know the number above for sure if $m=2, n=4?$
>
> (Notice that 'know for sure' means $A$ knows the number and which card this number is from. For example, if $n=2,m=2$, $A$ can know $0$ number above the cards.

I have no idea how to start at all.
I have a feeling that this question seems incomplete in the sense that some information is missing. But I do not know what.

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "know the number above"? That sounds like poor phrasing to me. Do you mean "know the number on the card", IE which card maps to which number?

Answer (score 1):

(The first part is for the specific case of $n = 2, m  = 4$ only.
The second part is for $n = 2$.
For the third part, I don't know how to deal with $n > 2$. I would love to hear your thoughts.)

Let the cards be $a, b, c, d$.

Claim: A can only guarantee that he knows at least 1 card.

**Proof that 1 is the upper bound.**
Consider the mapping:   $\{a,b\} \rightarrow 1, \{ a,c\} \rightarrow 1, \{ a,d\} \rightarrow 1, \{b,c\} \rightarrow 2, \{c,d\} \rightarrow 3, \{ d,b\} \rightarrow 4$.
This is satisfied by $ (1, 2, 3, 4) $ and $(1, 4, 2, 3)$, so all that $A$ knows is $ a = 1$. $_\square$

**Proof that $A$ will know at least 1 card.**
Main idea:  If $A$ hears a number at least twice, then the card that appears in the intersection of these pairs, must be equal to this number.

Since $A$ hears 6 numbers out of 4 possible distinct numbers, hence he must hear at least 1 number at least twice. So he can determine at least this card.   $_\square$

Note: This argument tells us to look at cases where the frequency is $(3, 1, 1,1)$, and hope to show that we can only determine 1 card, which turns out to be the worst case scenario described above. Otherwise, we would be able to determine at least 2 cards, since every other frequency has at least 2 values that are $ \geq 2$.

---

For $n=2, m \geq 3$, we can determine at least $m - 3$ cards. This is the best that we can do.

$m= 3, n = 2$. There are 3 pairs mapping to 3 numbers. The frequency $(1,1,1)$ might allow us to determine 0 cards. This is possible: the $\{b, c, d \}$ rotation of the worst case scenario above.

$m = 5, n = 2$. There are 10 pairs mapping to 5 numbers. The frequency $(4, 3, 1, 1, 1)$ might allow us to determine at most 2 cards. This is possible:
1) If the pair has $a$, map to 1.
2) Else, if the pair has $b$, map to 2.
3) For the remaining pairs on 3 cards, do the $\{ b,c,d\}$ rotation above.

**Proof that $m - 3$ is an upper bound.**
For the general $m \geq 3$, there are $\frac{ m (m-1) } { 2}$ pairs mapping to $m$ numbers. The frequency $(m-1, m-2, m-3, \ldots, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1 )$ might allow us to determine at most $m - 3$ cards. This is indeed possible using a mapping generalized from $m = 4, 5$. $_\square$

**Lemma:** $k$ distinct numbers can be heard at most $k (m-1) - {k \choose 2}$ times.
Set up the standard bijection with the complete graph on $m$ vertices. Each edge corresponds to a pair, each vertex corresponds to a card. The $k$ distinct numbers correspond to $k$ of the $m$ vertices. A number can be heard only if the vertex lies on the edge.
Since the $k$ vertices lie on exactly  $k (m-1) - {k \choose 2}$  edges (Each vertex has $m-1$ edges, and we double count by the complete graph on $k$ vertices), hence the lemma follows. $_\square$.

**Proof that $A$ will know at least $m-3$ cards.**
Suppose that there are at least 4 values that are heard at most once. Then, the other $m- 4$ values are heard at least ${m\choose 2 } - 4$ times.
Since $ {m\choose 2 } - 4 > (m-4)(m-1) - { m - 4 \choose 2 } $ (by expanding the inequality), this contradicts the previous lemma.
Thus, at most 3 values are heard at most once, so at least $m-3$ values are heard at least twice, so we can determine at least $m-3 $ values. $_\square$

---

Now for $n > 2 $ .... this seems messy. I'm not familiar enough with the higher dimensional analogy of the graph theory edge bijection that we have for $n = 2$.

It is not immediately obvious that the above could generalize. The main concerns I have are
1) What is the analogue of the $\{ b, c, d \}$ rotation?
2) For $n=3$, a number could be heard $m-2$ times and still not uniquely determine the card. Can we increase this further? What happens for $ n > 3$?
3) What is the analogue of the lemma?

Answer (score 0):

Partial Answer (to be completed):

Here's an alternate construction of the problem that might help:

Let us define $_nC_m$ as the subset of the powerset of $[n]=\{1,...,n\}$ of elements with cardinality $m$. And, let $\sigma$ be some permutation of $[n]$.

$B$ picks some choice function $f:\:_nC_m\to[n]$, and you are given $\sigma\circ f$.

$B$'s chooses $f$ in an attempt to minimize your knowledge of $\sigma$. How much of $\sigma$ do you know?

Comment: FYI I disagree that min(S) is the best option. I can get an assignment where you only know 1 card for $n = 2, m = 4$.